# Confused About API Results

Tags: api, civicase

Right now I am using the API Explorer (in 4.7.21) just to get the pieces I need for some custom code in Drupal.  I am just very confused about what the API Explorer is returning.  I am guessing this me not a bug.

If I execute the following with the Case ID of 223 then I should get back the contact assigned to that case.

```
$result = civicrm_api3('CaseContact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => array("contact_id"),
  'id' => 223,
));
```

When I execute this I get the contact for case 224.

If I use the API to query for the *Subject* of the case for ID 223 I get the expected results and the same for 224.

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Case', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => array("subject"),
  'id' => 223,
));
```

If anyone sees my error here I would appreciate it. If this is a bug I am glad to put it only issues.civicrm.org.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be 'case_id' => 223 instead of 'id' => 223 for the CaseContact one. It seems to work with either on the public demo, but that might be coincidence - in the civicrm_case_contact table the 'id' field is an autoincrement technically unrelated to case_id, but may or may not match the case_id depending on creation order, multiple clients, and other happenings.

I would use 'case_id', like so

`$result = civicrm_api3('CaseContact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => array("contact_id"),
  'case_id' => 223,
));`